# I need to write a dictionary in which it has both strings and values

Tags: python

```
#start the student array
Student = {}
#Menu to prompt the user if he wants to add, remove or modify a grade
while (True):
    print ("1. Add Student")
    print ("2. Remove Student")
    print ("3. Modify Grade")
    print ("4. Print all grades")
    print ("5. Exit")

    print("Welcome to the school dashboard system, choose one of the options");
    #prompt the user for a choice
    choice = input("Enter your choice: ");
#choice 1 will save the student name and grade
if (choice == 1):
#raw input meaning is accepting both values and strings
    name = raw_input("Enter student name: ")
   grade = raw_input("Enter the grade for the student: ")
   Student[name] = grade

#choice number 2 will delete the student from the list
elif (choice == 2):
    name = raw_input("Enter the student name: ");
#delete the student from the list
    del Student[name]

#choice number 3 will modify the grade for the student
elif (choice == 3):
    name = raw_input("Enter the student name: ")
    grade = raw_input("Enter the new grade for the student: ")
 #save in the student array
    Student[name] = grade

#choice number 4 will print all of the information about students and grades
elif (choice == 4):
#print the student list
    print (Student)

#This choice will exit the menu
elif (choice == 5):
     print("Thanks for using the System")
     break
```

I need to make a dictionary that accepts both values and string and prompts the user to add, modify and delete information. When I try to run there is an error that says 'break' outside loop, can someone please help me.

Comment: All your code after `choice = input("Enter your choice: ");` is outside the loop. Tou need to shift it 4 spaces to the right.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is not indented properly. Indentation (leading white spaces) in Python are used to group statements. Your code after this comment `#choice 1 will save the student name and grade` is out of the while loop, and so is the `break`at the end. Hence the error message.

This will work. <-- Also changed input to take either a string or an int according to usage.

```py
#start the student array
Student = {}
#Menu to prompt the user if he wants to add, remove or modify a grade
while (True):
    print ("1. Add Student")
    print ("2. Remove Student")
    print ("3. Modify Grade")
    print ("4. Print all grades")
    print ("5. Exit")
    print("Welcome to the school dashboard system, choose one of the options")
    #prompt the user for a choice
    choice = int(input("Enter your choice: "))
    #choice 1 will save the student name and grade
    if (choice == 1):
    #raw input meaning is accepting both values and strings
        name = str(input("Enter student name: "))
        grade = str(input("Enter the grade for the student: "))
        Student[name] = grade
    #choice number 2 will delete the student from the list
    elif (choice == 2):
        name = str(input("Enter the student name: "))
    #delete the student from the list
        del Student[name]
    #choice number 3 will modify the grade for the student
    elif (choice == 3):
        name = str(input("Enter the student name: "))
        grade = str(input("Enter the new grade for the student: "))
    #save in the student array
        Student[name] = grade
    #choice number 4 will print all of the information about students and grades
    elif (choice == 4):
    #print the student list
        print (Student)
    #This choice will exit the menu
    elif (choice == 5):
        print("Thanks for using the System")
        break
```